# Problem with codeigniter's redirect function

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, header, superglobals

This may be a n00b topic but, anyways, I have been having a rather difficult and strange time with this bug. Basically I was working on a controller method for a page that displays a form. Basically, I was debugging the form's submitted data by var dumping the form input using codeigniter's `$this->input->post` function like so:

```
var_dump($this->input->post('first_name'));
```

Every other day this has worked, but today I was finding that when I dumped post variables to the browser it would return false as if they had no values even though they did have values when I submitted the form. Then I tried accessing the variables through PHP's POST superglobal array directly like so:

```
var_dump($_POST['first_name']);
```

and that returned empty as well so then I tried dumping the entire post array like so:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

and it was empty as well despite the fact that I filled out the entire form. Nevertheless, the records in my MySQL database were being updated (which means that the form was submitting even though my $_POST variables appeared empty).

Also, I reasoned that normally, if I var dumped variables in the controller function before a redirect function call that it should give me a 'Headers already sent' error but it never did. It just redirected me to the supposed success page instead of dumping my variables.

So for the about 2 hours I thought that my POST data wasn't being sent and re-checked the code for errors and began commenting out statements one by one until I could find the culprit statement in my script.

Finally, I commented out a chunk of code that sets a success message an redirects, like so:

```
/*
if($record_updated_successfully)
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', $this->lang->line('record-updated-successfully'));
}
redirect('admin/success_page');
*/
```

and only then did the script start dumping out all my previous variable dumps using codeigniter's `$this->input->post` function as well as the `$_POST` superglobal array.

So ok, if the script does indeed redirect me despite the variable dumps sending output before headers are sent then I can see why the $_POST variables would appear empty.

So then the real question is why the script would still redirect despite my sending of output before headers are sent? Has anyone ever experienced this?

Any help with this would be appreciated.

EDIT: with respect to loading the view here's a simplified version of my script looks like
with the debugging var dump statements:

```
function some_controller_method() {
    var_dump($this->input->post());
    var_dump($_POST);

    // some code

    if($this->input->post('form_action') == 'update record') {
        // code that runs when the form is submitted
        /*
         * ...
         */

        if($record_updated_successfully)
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', $this->lang->line('record-updated-successfully'));
        }
        redirect('admin/success_page');
    }

    $this->load->view('my-view-file.php');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I can't be sure, I'm going to assume you were outputting things like the var_dump() in your view file. A view is not executed at the time you call it, for example:

```
   $this->load->view('some_view');
   echo "hi!";
```

In a controller will not result in the contents of some view followed by "hi". It will results in "hi" followed by the contents of some view. The view is actually output after everything else in the controller has run.

This is the only thing that comes to mind with the information you've presented. I'd have to see more code to offer a different diagnosis.

Comment: Something not right about your description of the problem. You claim `$_POST` is unpopulated, but your redirect is inside a conditional that depends on a post value.

Comment: No, that variable $record_updated_successfully is set via a call to a model function and anyways I said near the end of my question that I understood why the $_POST superglobal was empty. My question really was why a call to the redirect function, which might probably invoke PHP's own header function (e.g. header('Location: http://somesite.com')), why it would redirect me despite the fact that I echoed or var_dumped output to the browser before headers are sent. In a way, I'm asking why it wouldn't stop the script execution with an 'Headers already sent ...' error. I probably worded it unclear

Comment: The only circumstance I know when it would redirect me even I sent output to the browser before headers are sent is when I have output buffering to turned on but as far as I know I don't have have turned anywhere in my scripts and I don't think Codeigniter turns it on by default either. So that's why I'm confused. Anyways, sorry for the original question being confusing and not to the point. I just wanted to give enough background info.

Comment: A redirect is a header. If you have sent anything - actually sent something - to the browser before the header it will not work. This is a fact of life for all browsers. You may think you've sent something and then redirected, but you did not.

Answer (score -1):

I had "the same" problem and I found an `unset()` function in a loop in my code. Perhaps this will help.